# calculating sum of squares in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there anyway i can calculate the sum of the square of objects in an array

`a=[1,2,3,4]`
`sum of square = 1+4+9+16`

Please i'm try to find a way to do this.

Comment: Did you try *anything* before asking here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a.map{|x| x**2}.inject(0, &:+)
```

Comment: You don't even need the "0" or the `&` in the `inject`; a simple `reduce(:+)` will work.

Comment: or just `a.inject {|sum, item| sum + item*item }`

Comment: @d11wtq: he can drop the &, but not the 0 (or [] will return nil).

Comment: @dnnx, can you please explain the functions of the code, though i have tested it and it worked perfect

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau, it worked too but seem to give a different answer for a = [4,8,2,5,2,6], using a.map{|x| x**2}.inject(:+) and a.inject {|sum, item| sum + item*item }

Comment: a.inject(0) {|sum, item| sum + item*item }

Comment: @maprihoda: [2,3].inject { |sum, i| sum + i ** 2 } #=> 11, [2,3].inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + i ** 2 } #=> 13. And also: [].inject { |sum, i| sum + i ** 2 } #=> nil

Comment: @tokland - without 0 it works only for sequencies starting from 1 because 1 ** 2 == 1, so the first sum can be 1 without problem. So your solution is the most correct one (also with empty []). Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
p a.sum{|n| n*n} # => 30
```

Comment: sum requires rails (active_support)

Comment: @stmllr Not since [Ruby 2.4](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Comment: True. I didn't know that. Very nice